# @reach/tabs - How to switch all tabs at once on an MDX page (React + Gatsby + MDX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to create a Tab component for a Gatsby site. If I have a page with multiple tabs with the same labels:

```
Heading 1

First tab block
Tab 1 | Tab 2
Content Tab 1

Second tab block
Tab 1 | Tab 2
Content Tab 1 for the second block

Third tab block
Tab 1 | Tab 2
Content Tab 1 for the third block
```

What I want is that when I switch to "Tab 2" all tabs on-page should switch to "Tab 2".

To achieve this:

1. I created a 'CoLocatedTabs' component (with controlled behavior)
   Code: https://github.com/gaurav-nelson/gatsby-gitbook-starter/blob/master/src/components/tabsTest.js
2. Imported it into MDX (twice)
   Code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gaurav-nelson/gatsby-gitbook-starter/master/content/introduction.mdx
3. In the rendered version I get two separate tab components which don't talk to each other.

I understand that both components are different and have there own index. Is there any way to globally handle index for all tabs component on a page in MDX?

Or any workarounds to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://github.com/alexkrolick/ for creating [MDX observable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdx-observable).

See the demo at https://codesandbox.io/embed/gatsby-mdx-tabs-linked-state-demo-rkb8v